# After page reload vue router push doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a function that adds a random name of the month to the url, it stops working if after clicking on the function to reload the page, the url does not change, what's the problem?

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filters: [],
      mounts: [
        'january',
        'february',
        'march',
        'april',
        'may',
        'june',
        'july',
        'august',
        'september',
        'october',
        'november',
        'december',
      ],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.params.filter': function (value) {
      console.log('value:', value)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const routeFilters = this.$route.params.filter

    if (Array.isArray(routeFilters) && routeFilters.length > 0) {
      this.filters = routeFilters
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.mounts.length)
      this.filters.push(this.mounts[randomIndex])
      const path = `/auth/${this.filters.join('/')}/`
      this.$router.push({ path })
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page shouldn't be getting reloaded when using vue-router. Reload individual components if that is the needed functionality. When setting 'path' you are leading and ending with '/'.
Try removing the { } around path. If you put the 'path' string into .push directly, asin:

```
this.$router.push(`/auth/${this.filters.join('/')}/`);
```

you should notice that

```
this.$router.push({`/auth/${this.filters.join('/')}/`});
```

(what you have currently) is a syntax error.

Comment: You are right, the page should not reload, but the user of my application can reload the page, and then if he clicks on the product filters, nothing will change in the url, and he will not receive anything, I tried your solution, unfortunately it does not work, I found output how to solve this problem, but I'm wondering if I'm right or not